# Prevent MS Word from collapsing all text under heading

Tags: microsoft-word

So I have section like so...

```
Paragraph 1

collapsible section here

Paragraph 2

Paragraph 3
```

However, when I put a heading on collapsible section, it swallows everything under it

```
Paragraph 1

- Collapsed section
```

I want it to be like

```
Paragraph 1

- collapsed section

Paragraph 2

Paragraph 3
```

Comment: Elaborating on Rich Michaels' answer... Your Paragraph 2 and Paragraph 3 headings need to be at the same outline level as your Paragraph 1 heading. They will then not collapse. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/outlining.htm#Big_Idea_6

Answer (score 1):

Only text that contains an Outline Level that is higher than the preceding outline level being collapsed can avoid being part of the collapsed string.

If you collapse at a Heading 1 level, then ALL text below it, including subordinate Headings 2 - 9 levels, and the body text below each of them will also collapse.

If you collapse at a Heading 2 level, then ALL text below it, including subordinate Headings 3 - 9 levels, and the body text below each of them will also collapse.

Collapsing works based on Outline Levels and what stops a Collapse is the occurrence of a Higher level.

Your problem most likely is an Outline assignment level on the specific paragraph that in your observation collapses when it should not.